# Getting protocol from the URL in controller

Tags: symfony

I Googled it but maybe my search keywords are useless so how can I get URL protocol in controller? IS it http:// or https://

```
http://whatever.com/app_dev.php/welcome

//I need to echo http:// protocol here
echo $request->getHost(); //echos whatever.com
echo $request->getBaseUrl(); //echos app_dev.php/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To check if request is `https` use:

```
$request->isSecure()
```

Check [doc](http://api.symfony.com/2.2/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html#method_isSecure) for more info

Answer (score 11):

You can use this in your controller :

```
$scheme = $this->getRequest()->getScheme();
```

Otherwise, here is a code allowing you to know all the values ​​returned by the server:

```
 foreach ($_SERVER as $key => $value) {
      echo $key.' => '.$value.'<br>';
    }
```

Comment: above `foreach` loop could be minimized to `print_r($_SERVER);`

Answer (score 3):

Pass request to the controller, get the scheme, or schema and host:

```
function doSomething(Request $request)
{   
    echo $request->getScheme();
    echo $request->getSchemeAndHttpHost();
}
```